# How to get date from date picker in android?

Tags: android, datepicker

I am using the `DatePicker` for my application. I want to get the date that I have selected (on the `DatePicker`), but it's not returning the selected date. It's always returning the current date. How can I get the selected date from `DatePicker`?

Any help will be appreciated.

```
    day = pickDate.getDayOfMonth();
    month = pickDate.getMonth() + 1;
    year = pickDate.getYear();
    readAndChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReadAndChoose);
    readAndChoose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "" + day + "-" + "" + month + "-" + ""
                    + year;
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();

            /*
             * Intent i = new Intent(BirthActivity.this,
             * CompassActivity.class); startActivity(i);
             */

        }

    });
```

I don't want create a `DatePicker` dialog but I want to use the DatePicker provided by Android.

Comment: Update the OP with the code you are currently using.

Comment: You need to set the listener for your date picker and get the date when the event triggers, onDateSetlistener

Comment: How to set listener for date picker .

Comment: There is any difference between date picker and date picker dialog

Comment: can you post your data picker code?.

Answer (score 4):

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener 
                = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth;
            day = selectedDay;

            // set selected date into textview
            tvDisplayDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
               .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
               .append(" "));

            // set selected date into datepicker also
            dpResult.init(year, month, day, null);

        }
    };
```

Refer Thsi link..May be this will help you.:- http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-date-picker-example/

Answer (score 2):

```
 public class pickerdate extends Activity {
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 private TextView mDateDisplay;
 private Button mPickDate;
 private int mYear;
 private int mMonth;
 private int mDay;

 static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
    mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);


    mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });


    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    updateDisplay();
}
private void updateDisplay() {
    mDateDisplay.setText(
        new StringBuilder()
                // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                .append(mDay).append("-")
                .append(mYear).append(" "));
}
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            updateDisplay();
        }
    };
    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                        mDateSetListener,
                        mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        }
        return null;
    }
 }
```

Main Layout File

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical">
 <TextView android:id="@+id/dateDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""/>
 <Button android:id="@+id/pickDate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Date Picker"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

The above code works. I hope this is exactly what your look for.

Comment: i don't want to use separate dialog. but i want use date picker provided by android.

Comment: Note : **This is no longer used. You should consider using `DatePickerFragment` instead of just the dialog**

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to do so:

1. Using `init()` method of the `DatePicker` passing in `OnDateChangedListener`.

   ```
      datePicker.init(
           datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth(),
           new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
               @Override
               public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                   selectedYear = year;
                   selectedMonth = monthOfYear;
                   selectedDayOfMonth = dayOfMonth;
                   Log.d(LOG_TAG, "selectedDate = " + selectedYear  + "-" + selectedMonth + "-" + selectedDayOfMonth );
                  //TODO save or use selected value here
               }//end onDateChangedListener

   });
   ```
2. Having a Button click or overriding `onPause` to get currently selected date when a certain action is to be taken or when user is leaving the screen.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onPause() {
       int selectedYear = datePicker.getYear();
       int selectedMonth = datePicker.getMonth();
       int selectedDay =  datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
       //TODO save or use selected value here
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need

```
// the call back received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;

        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Dj's answer would work. And if you want to use a calendar variable for storing the date then,

```
     public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        setDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

there's also a great tutorial [here](http://javapapers.com/android/android-datepicker/) which also has source code to download.

One thing to note, when compiling the source code, you need make SelectDateFragment class "static" in javapapers code as well as make populateSetDate() method static, and I also moved this code:

`mEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);`

to the onCreate() method. After that you could be able to compile the code.

MainActivity should look like this in the end after editing:

```
package com.javapapers.andoiddatepicker;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private static EditText mEdit;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
}

public void selectDate(View view) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new SelectDateFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
}

public static void populateSetDate(int year, int month, int day) {
    mEdit.setText(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
}

public static class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        populateSetDate(year, month+1, day);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
private void openCalendar() {
    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), (view, year, month, dayOfMonth) -> {

        date = getDateString(year, month, dayOfMonth);

    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    dialog.show();

}

private String getDateString(int year, int mMonth, int mDay) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(year, mMonth, mDay);
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    return dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
}
```

Comment: This is a very low quality answer. Please improve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is you where supposed to validate your day, month and year inside your OnclickListener event, check the edited code. I once had similar error

```
readAndChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReadAndChoose);
readAndChoose.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


day = pickDate.getDayOfMonth();
month = pickDate.getMonth() + 1;
year = pickDate.getYear();

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "" + day + "-" + "" + month + "-" + ""
                + year;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

        /*
         * Intent i = new Intent(BirthActivity.this,
         * CompassActivity.class); startActivity(i);
         */

    }

});
```